# php soapserver: Can't import external schema

Tags: php, soap, xsd, wsdl, soapserver

I am implementing a PHP SOAP server using a third party wsdl.  The included xsd has an reference to the external schema as bellow:

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xmldsig-core-20080610/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig"/>
```

The SoapClient with bellow code works perfectly:

```
$options                       = array();
$options['features']           = 1;
$options['trace']              = 1;
$options['connection_timeout'] = 2000;
$options['exceptions']         = 1;
$options['soap_version']       = SOAP_1_1;
$options['encoding']           = 'UTF-8';
$options["user_agent"]  = 'php-file_get_contents/'.phpversion();

$clent = new SoapClient( $wsdl, $options);
```

But  not the SoapServer

```
$options                       = array();
$options['features']           = 1;
$options['trace']              = 1;
$options['connection_timeout'] = 2000;
$options['exceptions']         = 1;
$options['soap_version']       = SOAP_1_1;
$options['encoding']           = 'UTF-8';

$server = new SoapServer($wsdl, $options);
```

Which trows the following error

```
SoapServer::SoapServer("http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xmldsig-core-20080610/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error\r\n in ..../index.php on line 54
PHP Warning:  SoapServer::SoapServer(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xmldsig-core-20080610/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" in ..../index.php on line 54
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xmldsig-core-20080610/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd' in .../index.php on line 54
```

The SoapClient was also throwing the same error, but which is resolved after adding the "user_agent" option.
I don't see a "user_agent" option for SoapServer.

am I missing something here?

I am able to access the url: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xmldsig-core-20080610/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd and able to download the xsd file

Edited: Added the actual xsd link.

Comment: *I am able to access the url: `http://www.w3.org/some_schema.xsd` and able to download the xsd file*   That can't be because there is no XSD at that URL.